# Redirect nginx to ssl docker sevice

Tags: docker, ubuntu, nginx, ssl

I have a server on Hetzner do I configured several services on doker. In this case Portainer and Node-red.
I have connected a ddns domain pointing to the server ip and configured via certbot standalone the certificates individually for each service.
I can access both correctly via the following links:
https://myfreedomain.ddns.net:9000 (portainer)
https://myfreedomain.ddns.net:1880 (node-red)

I would like to configure nginex in such a way that I can access the services via path and force an ssl redirect.
Example:
http://myfreedomain.ddns.net/portainer --> https://myfreedomain.ddns.net:9000
The certificates are loaded and configured in the individual services

NgineX site-enable configfile:

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name myfreedomanin.ddns.net;
ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/myfreedomanin.ddns.net/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myfreedomanin.ddns.net/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

location /portainer     {
    proxy_pass https://myfreedomanin.ddns.net:9000;
}
location /node-red {
    proxy_pass https://myfreedomanin.ddns.net:1880;
}
}
```

the default configuration file is also present

Comment: Im no nginex expert, but i think you just add a second server block with a redirect: ```server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myfeedomanin.ddns.net;
    return 301 https://myfeedomanin.ddns.net$request_uri;
}```

Comment: OK, now the redirect seems to be working.
But the problem persists. it seems to me that nginx loads the ssl certificate correctly.  But when I try to reach the specified service ( https://myfreedomanin.ddns.net/portainer or /node-red) each service tries to load its certificate (which would be the same) and I get the following response:
Portainer --> 404 page not found
node-red -->Cannot GET /node-red

Comment: ok solved. the problem was in the path syntax
location /portainer/ {
    proxy_pass https://myfreedomanin.ddns.net:9000/;
}
location /node-red/ {
    proxy_pass https://myfreedomanin.ddns.net:1880/;
}